# Is there any possible way to remove the 1st character of a String using O(1) time complexity in C++?

Tags: c++, string, substring, erase

Suppose a String `str = "Shajib"`;
I want to remove the first character 'S' from "Shajib". After removing `str = "hajib"`.
I want to perform this task in O(1) Time complexity in C++

If a string is `str = "Shajib"`

1. `str = str.substr(1);`    //O(string size)
2. `str.erase(str.begin());` //O(string size)

I want to calculate this in O(1) time in C++ to rearrange the index.

Comment: No, but you could create a C-string or a string view.

Comment: no. Though you can keep a flag seperate from the string to indicate the the first character should be ignored. A counter if you need to "remove" more than a single character. Why do you need to do this in `O(1)` ?

Comment: I mean once you do print the string, that is also O(N), hence it would help if you explain why removing a character being `O(N)` too is an issue

Comment: as @jabaa mentioned, `std::string_view` can be a solution for that

Comment: Depending on what you have to do with it `str.c_str()+1` might be an option.

Comment: I think this is a case of [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Even though copying the characters is formally O(n), the time for actually copying 5 characters is in the nanosecond range. Will anyone notice if it takes 1 ns or 5 ns??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible using a `std::string` - the string needs to deallocate the entire piece of memory allocated for the contained string in it's destructor and therefore needs to know where that memory starts. Most implementations of `std::string` are designed such that the start of the allocated memory and the start of the contained string are the same (which keeps the size of the `std::string` object small), so moving the pointer to the start of the string would necessarily mean losing track of the allocated memory.

What you can do is create a `std::string_view` from the string and then use the `remove_prefix` method, which is O(1) because `std::string_view` only points to the string contained with the `std::string` and does not create a copy. However, that means you would have to make sure that the `std::string` object you created it from is kept in scope and in the same location for the entire time that you're using the string view, and you also can't modify the string using the string view.

Alternatively, if it's absolutely vital that the string be moved or be modified after removing the first character, you may want to use a `std::deque<char>` instead, which is the only C++ structure which guarantees O(1) deletion from either end.